# How to get public's image via facebook api?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api

I want to show newsfeed from facebook in my wp8 app. I made a query to Graph API "me/home", an got a newsfeed. And I need an image of each authors of feed. For example a have a piese of newsfeed look like

```
  "id": "107619212653885_433558870059916", 
  "from": {
    "category": "News/media website", 
    "name": "ФОКУС", 
    "id": "107619212653885"
  }, 
  "message": "Дарт Вейдер никак не угомонится. Завтра будет поздравлять прекрасных дам. http://focus.ua/kiev/263541/\r\n\r\n8 марта было в \"Звездных войнах\"?",
```

In "from" I have id, and if I use query

```
107619212653885?fields=cover
```

I can get a cover's "source".  Here the [link](http://www.facebook.com/focus.ua) of this public. But, in source - picture with snowdrops, and I need a picture with red "Ф", because in newsfeed I see this picture, not with snowdrops. So, how can I get this picture?

**Answer**  `107619212653885/picture`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will need the user id. With the user_id you can get the image of the user through a GET call.

example

string uid
stream response
HTTP1.Get ('http://graph.facebook.com/' + uid/picture?redirect=false, response)